# The maximal domain of the function $f(z)=z^3$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How to approach to quastion like:

What is the maximal domain of the function (for example) $f(z)=z^3$

What are the steps?

---

I know that $z^3=x^3-3y^2x+(3yx^2-y^3)i$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Informally, the maximum domain is the set of all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ for which the "expression makes sense."

In your case, $z^3$ yields a valid expression for any $z \in \mathbb{C}$ thus the maximal domain is $\mathbb{C}$.

Would you consider $z^{-3}$ then this would not makes sense for $z=0$ as you'd divide by $0$. But it makes sense for any other $z$. So the maximal domain is  $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$. The complement of this set is the maximal domain.

Generally, for a rational functions what you need to do is to find all values where the denominator is $0$.